# If $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^4+y^4+z^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{29}$, prove that $x^4+y^4+z^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{29^4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups, diophantine-equations

> If $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^4+y^4+z^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{29}$, prove that $x^4+y^4+z^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{29^4}$.

I have no idea where to start, but this is my abstract algebra homework, so I think we have to use machinery from abstract algebra. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean, the obvious thing you might immediately suspect is that this is because that sum of quartic powers being divisible by 29 implies that each of the individual terms is divisible by $29$.

Comment: $x^4 + y^4 + z^4 = 0$ mod $29$ implies $x = y = z = 0$ mod $29$ and therefore $x^4 = y^4 = z^4 = 0$ mod $29^4$. This is because the fourth powers mod $29$ are only $0,1,7,16,20,23,24,25$ and they don't non-trivially add to $0$. Maybe you can prove this with machinery but it is easy enough to check by hand

Comment: Why did you do this? Do not change or remove the question because it may be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: Ishigami, please stop defacing this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a plan. If you could show that the first congruence is possbile only, if all the variables are divisible by $29$, then you would be done, right?

You could actually brute force it. Cyclicity of the group $\mathbb{Z}_{29}^*$ means that $x^4$ takes seven distinct non-zero values modulo $29$, namely the residue classes in the set
$$S=\{1,7,16,20,23,24,25\}.$$ 
This is basically because $4\mid(29-1)$. Anyway, listing all the $8^3$ possibilities, and checking that "all zeros" is the only solution is doable.

The first reduction to the workload is to observe that no fourth power is $\equiv-1\pmod{29}$. This implies that there is no solution with a single variable divisible by $29$, and the rest non-divisible. So it suffices to exclude the possibility of a solution with all $x^4,y^4,z^4\in S$. Still $7^3$ cases remain (taking into account permutatins of the variables actually a lot less).

But $S$ is clearly also a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{29}^*$. If the sum of any three elements of $S$ is zero, say $u+v+w\equiv0\pmod{29}$, we can multiply this congruence by the inverse of $u$, stay inside the subgroup $S$, and find a solution $1+vu^{-1}+wu^{-1}\equiv0\pmod{29}$. This means that w.l.o.g. we can assume that $u=1$. Only $49$ cases remain.

As $27\notin S$, we can see that $v\neq1\neq w$, and as $14\notin S$, also $v\neq w$. At this point we take into account the symmetry $v\leftrightarrow w$, and there are ${6\choose 2}=15$ cases remaining. The remaining checks involve verifying that if
$u,v\in\{7,16,20,23,24,25\},u<v$, then $u+v\neq-1\pmod{29}$. This is easy because either $u=7$ and $v\neq21$, or $29<u+v<50$.

The conclusion is that the plan worked. For $x^4+y^4+z^4$ to be divisible by $29$ it is necessary that all the variables are divisible by $29$. Therefore the sum of their fourth powers is divisible by $29^4$.

---

I think it may be possible to make more clever use of the fact that the elements of $S$ are seventh roots of unity.

A possibility that occurred to me is to prove that for all triples $(u,v,w)$ of distinct elements of $S\simeq C_7$ we can find an element $x\in S$ such that either $x\{u,v,w\}\cap \{u,v,w\}$ has two elements, or the intersection is empty. In neither case is it possible that $u+v+w=0$ (when also $xu+xv+xw=0$): in the former case we have an obvious contradiction, and in the latter case we contradict the fact that the sum of all elements of $S$ is zero, and the two triples cover all but one element of $S$.

Unfortunately this is not true. Any coding theorist should be familiar with the case that inside a cyclic group of order seven the triple $\{1,g,g^3\}$ intersects all its shifts in a singleton. Something else?

Anyway, checking those fifteen cases is probably simpler. If somebody comes up with some other clever trick, I'll give a bounty.

Comment: Your (rather neat) reduction to the $x=1$ case only holds if $x\neq 0$. According to Cocopuff's comment, this cannot happen (if the fourth powers he gives are correct, the comment seems correct).

Comment: I excluded the case $x=0$ earlier. If $u=0$, then $v=-w$, and we would see $-1=v/w$ in the group $S$. That was the purpose of the paragraph: "The first reduction..." Sorry about not making that clear.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were trying to skip the brute force (and I didn't read your question fully enough). Also, I meant to say "if $x, y, z\neq 0$", not just $x$.

Comment: Note that since $x,y,z$ must be distinct, you can quickly use the fact that the sum of $S$ is a multiple of $29$ to show that any two solutions must have exactly one value in common. And there must be at least seven solutions, since $x,y,z$ and $s\in S$ gives a (different) set $sx,sy,sz$. But that leads you to the projective plane over $\mathbb Z_2$, so every pair of $x,y\in S$ must be in a solution, which is impossible.